# How to use display property in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive, display

I need to use some properties of Bootstrap explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

I write the following code in my template:

```
<div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm">
            <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
            <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
            <p class"d-sm-none d-md-block">This has to be hidden in small sizes</p>                
        </div>
   </div>
```

The problem is that it isn't working. I don't know if I had to import some scss class, but the teacher specified that we only need to use css.

Comment: Try to make your code in `JSFiddle` so anyone can debug it and make it running for you.

Comment: Also if you want to write your own `CSS` that will work according to screen sizes then you can write your `CSS` code using the [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your paragraph element class attribute is missing `=` sign. Fix it by

```
<p class="d-sm-none d-md-block"> ... </p>
```

Secondly, gladly that you included a link to Bootstrap display property documentation. If you read through that, `.d-{breakpoint}-{value}` means from the `{breakpoint}` and **up**, it will display as `{value}`. So:

`d-sm-none` -> display as none from breakpoint sm and **up**

`d-md-block` -> display as block from breakpoint md and **up**

Combining those 2 will give you the effect of display none between the breakpoint sm and md.

If you want to hide the paragraph for small screens, you can set its display to none from the beginning, and change it to block for breakpoint md:

```
<p class="d-none d-md-block"> ... </p>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/104005/

By the way, `col-sm` class on the `<div>` is unnecessary. It's only useful when you have more than 1 column and you want them to have equal width.

Answer (score -1):

Are you importing Bootstrap?

Add the following to your `<head>` if not.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```